# How to right trim multiple groups of character sequences with regexp?

Tags: regex

I am wondering if this is possible with regexp;

Given this test string:

`DgEAAAAAAAA=`

I would like to remove (replaced with "") all `A=`, `AA` and `BA`s of the end of the string until it is not longer possible.

So in this case, `DgEAAAAAAAA=` would be `DgEA`.

In my head, I thought something like `(AA)|(A=)$` but I can't figure the correct syntax out, or if its event possible)

Comment: `(\w)(\1+=)` replace this with `$1`

Comment: Since you want to remove it from the end, maybe you can look into reading backward in regex. Then you might be able to use `(AA)*(AB)*(=A)*(?=\w+)` (notice how the groups are reversed). The problem that using `(?<=\w+)(AA)*(BA)*(A=)*` (groups are the 'normal' way around) in the normal left-to-right fashion, is that it will match greedy. Simply taking the group `AA` as the first match, and then ending up with a single `=` at the end. So maybe if you read it in reverse, you'll be able to get it to work.

Comment: I didn't know that the `$` character also corresponded to the end of a string, instead of only the end of a line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(A=|AB|AA)*$
```

It will look for any number of consequent occurrences of the groups at the end of a string.

Comment: I would like to know the regexp that replaces groups of sequences of characters, not exclusively starting with a specific letter (A).

Comment: Oops, that's totally my bad. I'll check it out, and remove my answer.

Comment: Hey, its not repeating values I want to trim. It is specific words, grouping of characters. I've updated the main question.

Comment: I'm so sorry I keep reading your answer incorrectly. I'll remove it and try again.